# Unable to download any snap package - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, snap

I reinstalled snapd in ubuntu 18.04

by using command -

```
sudo apt purge snapd
sudo apt install snapd
```

then I ran

```
❯snap debug connectivity
Connectivity status:
 * PASS
```

everything was working fine so i proceeded to install snap package

```
❯ snap install scrcpy
```

which gave me this output

```
2020-07-04T12:44:35+05:30 INFO Waiting for restart...
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "core18" (1754) from channel "stable" (Get https://canonical-lcy01.cdn.snapcraft.io/download-origin/canonical-lgw01/CSO04Jhav2yK0uz97cr0ipQRyqg0qQL6_1754.snap?token=1593860400_9d59595be2d5a313a86cd070771489c6a5a0d869&interactive=1: EOF)
```

then I tried to install it again but this time the output was

```
❯ snap install scrcpy
error: unable to contact snap store
```

and then I ran  `snap debug connectivity` again which gave the output

```
Connectivity status:
 * api.snapcraft.io: unreachable
error: 1 servers unreachable
```

what's the issue here?

Note- I am not using any proxy.

Comment: sometimes the snap store can be down itself, try again with some time, when you run `snap search scrcpy` does it give any output?

Comment: I am facing this issue from the past 24 hours by now and search command is giving the same output ``` error: unable to contact snap store``` @JoKeR

Comment: Try: `ping -c3 api.snapcraft.io`

Comment: for some reason, ping command is not working too, I tried `ping -c3 api.snapcraft.io` and `ping google.com` both gave 100% packet loss

Comment: that is some misconfiguration with your network

Comment: Can you access google normally via web browser?

Comment: yes, all websites are working fine @JoKeR .where to look for that misconfiguration?

Comment: also `ping 8.8.8.8` works fine @JoKeR